# Fixed point property of spaces having same homotopy type

Tags: homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose X and Y have same homotopy type.X as a topological space has fixed point property.Can we conclude anything about fixed point property of Y?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. For example, $X$ could be a point. Then you're asking whether a contractible space $Y$ has the fixed point property. This isn't true in general (although the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) is a weaker result along these lines): for example, $Y = \mathbb{R}$ doesn't have the fixed point property.

More generally, if $X$ is any space, then $Y = X \times \mathbb{R}$ is a homotopy equivalent space which doesn't have the fixed point property. This suggests that at the very least we should take $X$ and $Y$ to both be compact. Unfortunately, [this is also not enough](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141501/fixed-point-property-for-maps-of-compacts).

More can be said with more restrictions. For example, the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) can be used to show that a compact triangulable space which is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ has the fixed point property (in fact it suffices that it have the same cohomology ring).